# use CSS for table in joomla article

Tags: html, css, joomla3.0

I need to use CSS to format a table in Joomla 3.x, I really don't know how to do this.  I only need it for a few pages and it's to display a group of names, not style a page etc....

I'm using gantry 5 enabled template.

Answer (score 0):

Ganty 5 templates come with their own styling for tables and this can be applied by adding appropriate CSS classes e.g. `<table class="table">…</table>`. See http://demo.gantry.org/features/typography as an example.

You can also add custom CSS to a Gantry 5 template as per http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/tutorials/adding-a-custom-style-sheet or add your own inline css styling.